# OpenCV FileNode Object Get Raw Content

Tags: c++, opencv

Is it possible to get a FileNode's raw content?

for example:

**test.json**

```
{
   "app_1":{ 
       "params":{ "p1":12, "p2":{ "p21":13, "p22":"str", "p23":12.5 } } 
   }
   "app_2":{ 
       "params":{ "p33":45, "p2":{ "p24":77, "p52":56 } } 
   }
}
```

**test.cpp**

```cpp
...
FileStorage fs("test.json", FileStorage::READ | FileStorage::FORMAT_JSON);
cout << GetRawContent(fs["app_1"]["params"]);
```

**Prints out:**

```
{ "p1":12, "p2":{ "p21":13, "p22":"str", "p23":12.5 } }
```

Comment: Does the result need to be *exactly* as it appears in the file? If it doesn't and you can't find another way then maybe you could try serializing the `FileNode` back into a string.

Comment: @Kerndog73 NO! Although I am not prefer to serialize `FileNode` back into string again, however it is an acceptable solution.

Comment: If you told us why you need to do this then maybe we can find another way. I'm not intimately familiar with OpenCV but from what I can gather, it doesn't look like this is possible.

Comment: @Kerndog73 I have many Modules in my program. In fact I am trying to separate each Module configs from a single config file and pass them to the corresponding module as string (NOTE: the passed config string will bee parsed with `FileStorage module_fs(config_str, FileStorage::READ | FileStorage::FORMAT_JSON | FileStorage::MEMORY);`